# Uninstall MS Access 2007 Runtime via command-line

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, uninstallation

We have a really old Microsoft Access tool that is currently using the 2007 runtime. I need to update the users to the 2010 runtime but they are located on separate buildings so physically uninstalling the old is not very practical.  Does anyone know of a way to uninstall through the command line?  I found this one for 2010 but it doesn't work for 2007

http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Microsoft-Access-Runtime-2010-21278-program.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging I found the answer.  Run MsiExex with the product GUID

MsiExec.exe /qn+ /X{90120000-001C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}